# NameError ошибка

Tags: python-3.x

```
def konkurs_bal(zno_1, zno_2, zno_3, reg_k=1.02):
    message_1 = int(input("Введіть бал з української мови"))
    message_2 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з історії України"))
    message_3 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з математики або іноземної мови"))


rahunok = int(konkurs_bal (message_1 * 0.1 ))
print(rahunok)
```

Начинающий программист не знаю что делать.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "mir.py", line 5, in <module>
    rahunok = int(konkurs_bal (message_1 * 0.1 ))
    NameError: name 'message_1' is not defined
```

Comment: Переменная `message_1` является локальной, вы не можете обратиться  к ней за пределами функции. https://younglinux.info/python/local-global

Answer (score 1):

Вы совсем не объяснили, что вы хотите сделать. Что принимает ваша функция? Что вы хотите передать в функцию? Вот мои фантазии, попробуйте:

```
def konkurs_bal(zno_1=1, zno_2=1, zno_3=1, reg_k=1.02):
    message_1 = int(input("Введіть бал з української мови: "))
    message_2 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з історії України: "))
    message_3 = int(input("\nВведіть бал з математики або іноземної мови: "))
        
    result = ((message_1 * zno_1) + (message_2 * zno_2) + (message_3 * zno_3)) * reg_k 
    return result
    
rahunok = konkurs_bal(zno_1=0.1)

print(f'\n результат = {rahunok}')
```